# Problem with fetch when putting app online (Node.js -> Heroku)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I want to put my planner app online, but when I do, it no longer works. The fetch (network communication with database, can be viewed in the developer tools of your browser) stays "pending" for a while and then fails. I thought all I had to do was change the url to the online one instead of localhost. Another app I made has very similar code, I have compared the two but can't see why the fetch won't work online.

I did find it may have something to do with permissions and access-control but nothing I have tried so far works.

I have created a copy of my code on a public github repo with a new mongo cloud atlas account for demonstration.

https://github.com/AnneliesB/planitFork

Right now, when I've put the app online with the localhost link as url (see Javascripts folder -> config.js) and when I have nodemon running, it works. But having nodemon running to be able to use an app isn't exactly useful. I would like to be able to use the app online, without needing to have any processes running.

Comment: Not directly related but given the stack you are using, have you looked into parse-server?

Comment: Regarding the question it is not clear what you mean by 'the fetch'. Navigating to https://planit-develmode.herokuapp.com it does respond with a page so it is somewhat up?

Comment: Will strongly recommend that you move the secrets in your config folder out as environment variables (DB conn string and jwt secret). Those should never be checked into source control.

Comment: @cYrixmorten i have pushed it online on heroku, and i thought it worked. But then i closed my code editor where i had nodemon running. The pages are up, but trying to register or login does not work. As a result the index page also does not work and you cant load anything. So the fetch refers to getting and saving data from the db collection. // i will also use the .env file, thats something i saw after a friend tried to help earlier today. But for now, i’m leaving it like that until the website works and can communicate with the db when online.

Comment: I will also look into parse-server! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Have indeed served me well :) well, does the log on heroku reveal anything? There should at least be an error message, perhaps when connecting to mongodb

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IxImP5s.jpg More -> View logs

Comment: I checked the logs (which I didn't know you could check like that), but there isn't anything too remarkable. I got 2 warnings, which I haven't been able to replicate. They were the following:
- (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server 
- (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1

Comment: - (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: So you have an uncaught error, think you may be able too google a way for NodeJS to capture it so that you can print it to the log